# Dialog Overlay in Persistent Bottom Sheet

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

Is it possible to add overlay on a persistent bottom sheet as found in modal bottom sheet dialog ? I implemented a bottomsheet that has a framelayout in it and does some fragment transaction.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:elevation="4sp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/function_frame"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2sp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="#fafafa"
                android:elevation="4sp">

            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

When it is expanded and back button is pressed, fragment is removed from the stack. But when i used a modal dialog, the dialog is dismissed.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.function_frame);
    if (fragment.getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
        if (mBottomSheetBehavior.getState() == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
            mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
            return;
        }
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

So, I figured out using the persistent dialog would do the job better but I want the modal overlay on areas of the screen not covered by the sheet.

Comment: Do you find something about it? Im trying to do something similar to Uber BottomSheet and I will probably need this